# How to mange the Order of Ajax calls execution in this case

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page under which the the cust_id is passed from one page to another page (back and forth)

The issue i am facing is that sometimes the cust_id may be undefined or empty

In that case i want to fecth the customer_id based on the Ajax call
This is my code .

```
var cust_id = getParameterByName('cust_id');

$(document).on('click', '#saveaddress', function() {
 cust_id = ''
        if(cust_id==''||cust_id=='undefined'||cust_id=='')
        {

        }
    if(somecondition)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OMS/oms1/chdsavenewaddresslabel?mobile_number='+phonenumber+'&location='+location+'&cust_id='+cust_id+'&address1='+address1+'&address2='+address2+'&landmark='+landmark+'&locality='+locality+'&area='+area+'&city='+city+'&state='+state,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function(response) {



            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert('Error inside Fill form request');
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please correct the Error');
    }

});



function fetchCustomerId(uuid)
{
  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
       url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fetchcustomerId?uuid='+uuid,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function (responsesss) {
            var res = responsesss;
            var cust_id = res.Id;
       },   
        error: function (e) {
        }
    });
 return cust_id;
}
```

The issue i am facing is that the two Ajax calls are getting mixed up

Please let me know how to execute each Ajax call independently

Comment: Why don't you have a `$(document).ready()` function that calls `fetchCustomerId`

Comment: And second of all, why do you have the first function mapped to a document.onclick event?  Wouldn't that mean the function will fire whenever you click the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the promises documentation for jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/.

There is an example for chaining together two ajax calls.  You may need to rewrite your functions a bit, but it'' give you a good idea of what needs doing.

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```